# How to make an element bounce back like pong game after been translated?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make the translated element bounce back but it's just go out the screen, here's the code:

```html
<svg id="m" width="40" height="40">
        <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="red" stroke="red" stroke-width="1"/>
    </svg>
    
    <script>
let m = document.getElementById("m");

let start = function(e) {
  if(m.getBoundingClientRect().y>window.innerHeight || m.getBoundingClientRect().y<0){
      console.log("out")
      }
  else if(m.getBoundingClientRect().x>window.innerWidth || m.getBoundingClientRect().x<0){
      console.log("out")
      }
  
  m.style.transform = `translate(${e.x*2}px, ${e.y*2}px)`;
};

document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => start(e));
    </script>
```

Comment: You made the position of the circle directly dependent on the position of the cursor. What do you expect?

Comment: @trincot because I want it to move just like it's moving now, so how can I do both the bouncing and the movement? thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. Currently the ball is not moving freely -- its position is completely defined by the cursor. You need to define in which direction it will move and with which speed.

Comment: @trincot I think that makes sense, thanks a lot